# Request for bounty on Why isn't the 'Map Colors' fixup changing text colors?

Tags: discussion

Many apologies if this is unmannerly, but I don't know how else to request a bounty on [Why isn't the 'Map Colors' fixup changing text colors?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/122855/121005) Thank you.

The snag now is that  [Dietrich von Seggern](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/122855/why-isnt-the-map-colors-fixup-changing-text-colors#comment184579_123895) commented

> The Profile that you have sent uses wrong input color (other than in your initial screenshot): **C97 M55 Y28 K7** instead of C99 M98 Y18 K6. When I modify your profiles values it works as expected.

But I don't see and never input '**C97 M55 Y28 K7**' at all! I input "C99 M98 Y18 K6" as you can see in my screenshot

Answer (score 10):

First off, a bounty is an amount of reputation that a user offers out of their own reputation. So yes, in my humble opinion, asking someone else to do that is a bit, as you call it, unmannerly. Since you are just a few reputation points away from being able to bounty your own reputation, I'd say try and give a decent-ish answer somewhere, get an upvote, and take matters in your own hands.

What do you hope to achieve with the bounty? If it's specifically Dietrich's attention, I don't think a bounty's going to help. Judging by their profile, they haven't been around for over half a year now and bountying a question they once answered is not going to pop up any notifications that I know of.

Sorry for sounding kind of harsh, that isn't my intention. I read your question and if I knew the answer I'd've helped you then and there.